# How to load same FXML into different controller objects?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TabPane where I'm loading two (or more) files in two different tabs. These two files are loading the same controller class. Now, if I make change in one file and save, the contents of other file in the tab is also changing (However the original file remains unaltered). I want to create two separate controller objects for these two files. Is there anyway to do that? Please help.

Comment: Why don't you have two different controller classes for them?

Comment: no..it should be same..I just took an example of two files..There could be hundreds of files..All files will use the same controller. I just need separate objects for separate files.

Comment: Files? What are these files? Are these not FXML's/views?

Comment: It is actually JSON files which I'm loading in a TreeView on my left side of the SplitPane. When I click on each of these files, It will load a UI with JSON data on the right side of the SplitPane. This UI has one controller. So, whichever file I click from the treeview, it will load this UI using the same controller.

Comment: One file was loading on the right side at a time. Now I want to load multiple files. So I'm using a TabPane where each tab will load one file. But if I make some change in one file and save, since the controller is same, the table view in the other tab is also getting changed.

Comment: The UI displayed on the right side depends on the FXML you are loading, while the data depends on the data that you are providing to the controller. Each time you load a FXML a different instance of the controller class will be created. What files are you saving? Are these the same files? The data has got nothing to do with controller instance. If you have some issue, try and create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it for more clarity.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I think I found the issue. Will work out.